# Disable interactive SSH at user-level

Tags: ssh, security, remote-access

I connect to a server I don't control via SSH.

I use public key access and don't need to be able to connect with a keyboard-interactive password.

I would like to disable keyboard-interactive access to my user so that there is no way for others to hack in this way.

Since I don't control the server, is there a way to set up my user's config file to prevent keyboard-interactive access?

Answer (score 11):

If you have absolutely no control over the server, I don't see a way of doing this, as you don't control server settings, which is where this would have to be.

What you'd need to do is add this to the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Now, this would effectively disable password authentication for *all* users, which may be undesirable. What you could do then, is put this configuration directive in a Match block, so it only applies to your user, in the same config file:

```
Match user yourusername
PasswordAuthentication no
```

If you could get the server's admin to do this for you, it might be the way to go.

One other way is to set a really long, random and complicated password for your user, that way you're reasonably protected from random brute-force break-in attempts. Most attackers would likely be using some dictionary-based technique so as long as your password is long and random enough, it should be quite safe.

See "man sshd_config" for more details. Also, the solution I propose was suggested [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1487425).

Comment: This is helpful, but I do not believe that this would "have" to be done in the server settings, as you say. It is clear that when I use public-key authentication, the SSH daemon is checking the public key against a file in my user directory. There is no reason to believe that the server could not, in principle, check a user config file for appropriate actions to take regarding keyboard-interactive logins. Whether or not SSHD implements this, I do not know.

Comment: Indeed, the "KbdInteractiveAuthentication" and possibly the "ChallengeResponseAuthentication" settings in the "~/.ssh/config" file seem relevant, though I have not yet succeeded in getting them to work.

Comment: @Richard `~/.ssh/config` is only read by the client, not by the server. Sure, the server could, in principle, check a file in your home directory to check whether you want to allow password authentication. But it doesn't. In fact, sshd allows password logins even if your home directory doesn't exist; this can be a lifesaver in some circumstances, such as a hosed `/home` filesystem. The simple way to prevent others from logging in with your password is not to use a weak or reused password.

Comment: +1 for strong random password. I assume your current setup is such that you don't need to ever enter the account password? I usually use `pwgen 20` or similar to generate a strong random string. Be sure to write down the password somewhere for backup.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to edit this line  from file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` from `yes` to `no`:

```
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

Comment: That is not a user level setting.

Answer (score 0):

[I assume you're using BASH as your login shell.  If not, adjust appropriately...]

In `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, prepend a command specification to each line like this:

```
command="ssh_key=XXX /bin/bash -l" ssh-dss AAAA...K3E= me@mymachine
```

In `~/.bash-profile`, put the following trap at the top:

```
if [ "${ssh_key}" != "XXX" ]; then
  echo "${SSH_CLIENT}" | mailx -s "password login attempt!" me@mailservice
  exit
fi
```

Now you'll just get mail when someone uses a password to enter your account.